# Audience Targeting web part property missing while exporting the content search web part?

Tags: sharepoint-server, export, audience-targeting, cswp, web-part-property

I customized the CSWP then I exported that web part, After Exporting the CSWP web part the Audience targeting property is missing Which is from the Advanced section. I am not sure why that property is missing.

Please suggest me an idea to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's a common issue not only for `Content Search Web Part` but also for others web part like `Content Query web part`. what I think it is because of the default `FilterByAudience` property is set to **false**.

```
<property name="FilterByAudience" type="bool">False</property>
```

The available workaround is to **manually** reassign `Audience Target` again!